# problem with ToolStripSeparator

Tags: .net, winforms, toolstrip

I have a toolstrip. For this toolstrip, I am adding [`ToolStripSplitButton`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripsplitbutton.aspx) and for this [`ToolStripSplitButton`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripsplitbutton.aspx), I am adding toolstrip items, including [`ToolStripSeparator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripseparator.aspx). In the click event of the toolstrip items I am retrieving items from the [`ToolStripSplitButton`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripsplitbutton.aspx) dropdown using below code.

```
 ToolStripDropDown tditems = ((System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDownItem)(items[0])).DropDown;
foreach (ToolStripMenuItem item in tditems.Items)
{
//something here
}
```

As the dropdown items have both toolstrip items and [`ToolStripSeparator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripseparator.aspx) at runtime, it is giving following error.

> Additional information: Unable to cast
>   object of type
>   'System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripSeparator'
>   to type
>   'System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem'.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

If you are using .NET 3.5, you could use the [`OfType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) extension method as follows.

```
foreach (var item in tditems.Items.OfType<ToolStripMenuItem>())
{
    // something here
}
```