# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripSeparator' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem'

Tags: c#, winforms

```
foreach ( ToolStripMenuItem item in tsDDLEntry.DropDownItems)
```

when i run i have got this error message

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripSeparator' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem'.

Comment: possible duplicate of [problem with ToolStripSeparator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537394/problem-with-toolstripseparator)

Answer (score 3):

Obviously you have at least one toolstrip separator in dropdown items. When foreach loop tries to cast `ToolStripSeparator` to `ToolStripMenuItem` you get an exception, because separator is not a subclass of menu item. You can use LINQ [OfType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360913%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method to get items of certain type only:

```
foreach (var menuItem in tsDDLEntry.DropDownItems.OfType<ToolStripMenuItem>())
```

Or you can check each item manually:

```
foreach (object item in tsDDLEntry.DropDownItems)
{
    ToolStripMenuItem menuItem = item as ToolStripMenuItem;
    if (menuItem == null)
       continue;

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the options to ContectMenuStrip using ToolStripMenuItem as displayed:

```
ContextMenuStrip cmsOp = new ContextMenuStrip(); 
ToolStripMenuItem Option = new ToolStripMenuItem("ItemName");
cmsOp.Items.Add(Option);
```

"-" is considered a separator in ContectMenuStrip. So, if you are trying to add "-",then it will not be added to ContectMenuStrip. This will give an error while iterating items of ContectMenuStrip.